The request queue limit of the session is exceeded (no cookies/loadtest)
When performing a load test we are getting high error rates linked to the following error:
"The request queue limit of the session is exceeded".
I'm aware of the following posts and KB but struggling to see how they apply to us:
The request queue limit of the session is exceeded
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0858026
The reason I'm struggling to see the link is that when performing our load tests it appears that no cookie/session data is provided in the request. Additionally, my understanding is that each thread in our load test should run sequentially, so I find it strange that a queue would build up.
Is anyone able to suggest/explain why these errors could be happening and what the behavior is behind the scenes when requests start coming in with no session data?
My assumption was that a new and unique session ID would be created for the each request and this might be added to the queue but given we are not resubmitting the cookie on subsequent requests this queue should never grow.
I'll probably create a similar post on stack overflow targeted more at the ASP.Net implementation but thought I'd ask here first.
Thanks in advance for any support or suggestions,
Daniel
EDIT (Adding additional details as suggested by Marek):
So, we have a jmx file that was created in jmeter, this has been uploaded to BlazeMeter where the script is ran by our QA team. We usually run the script with 200 virtual users (threads). It is my understanding that the test is constructed with layers of Throughput Controllers which trickle down towards HTTP Requests, I assume that each request is considered a full loop / iteration and that because we have the "Clear cookies each iteration" option enabled any cookies that the server tries to set are discarded after 1 request.
EDIT (Adding additional details as suggested by Chandra):
We are running a headless system. Our front end is built with the .NET Core Rendering Host package provided by Sitecore. Both the CD servers and RH servers are hosted on Azure and situated behind an instance of Azure Front Door. We have 4 CD instances and 2 RH instances with auto scaling disabled. There is no rate limiting on the QA environment.

You need to add more information of how you execute the load test. What tool do you use, how do you trigger requests, etc

Hi Marek, I've added some additional information. Hopefully that makes things clearer. Thanks, Daniel

@Daniel can you add more details about your infrastructure and architecture?

Updated as suggested Chandra. Thank you.

@Daniel can you check Request and Response headers to see the value of session cookie? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614000/how-to-check-request-response-body-in-blazemeter-test. Is you script configured to retrieve all embedded resources?

Hi Anna, originally, I looked at the web server logs which showed no cookies/sessions being submitted.  For some reason, the server stopped logging these though, so I started looking at the jmeter file (set to no cookies). Lastly, i wrote a custom load testing tool which should also be using no cookies. The results for all are the request queue limit reached error.

Hi again Anna, I just saw that there was more text and a link hidden in your comment. I will try this now. Thanks.

Checking the BM logs confirms that no cookies/sessions are being sent in the request headers and so the behavior definitely doesn't match what SC and MS say it should be.
